# Is there an advantage to setting up web app in React JS if mobile app is going to be in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, architecture

I'll be starting a project, and due to reasons I'd like to use angular.

However I know that soon after we start the web app we'll also start a mobile app in React Native. Over this I have no control (thus no reason to suggest Native Script).

Setting personal preferences of developers aside, are there any reasons why we should consider React for the web too?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are many reasons to build both web and native targets with React:

- Both use JavaScript and JSX so you have less technical overhead.
- Both follow the same design patterns, so you have less technical overhead.
- If you plan for it, you can reuse logic. This can save a significant amount of time and improve parity between web and mobile apps.
- There are already a bunch of great resources out there on building applications that use ReactJS and React Native together, providing direction and momentum.